# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I imported the module correctly into pandas and called it correctly using import main and then main.main(data, 1,10,2.5) but I am getting an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-e9913b227737> in <module>()
----> 1 main.main(data, 1, 10, 2.5)


     38     dat_sh = data.shape[0]
     39     #Z = random.sample(range(0,U),k_max)
---> 40     Z = cf.centroid_finder(data,sp_atr,k_max)
     41 
     42     prototypes = {i: data[j:j+1].values.tolist()[0] for i,j in enumerate(Z)}


     11         for i in range(dat_sh):
     12             for j in range(dat_sh):
---> 13                 D[i][j] =  ed(sub_atr[i],sub_atr[j])
     14 
     15 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

ed is euclidean:

```
def ed(X2, X1):
    return sqrt(sum(np.subtract(X1,X2)**2))
```

Comment: What is `ed`? Where is it initialized and how?

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: ed is euclidean distance, ill post that code...its a lot so I wont post all the files @DYZ

Comment: could you also post all the `import` statements?

Comment: what you want from `for i in range(dat_sh): for j in range(dat_sh):`?The `sub_atr[i],sub_atr[j]` would be same.

Comment: If `ed` is a module, then `ed(...)` is illegal.

Comment: `ed` should `def` ealier than main

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion regarding the importing of **modules** vs **functions**.

It's possible to recreate your error with a simple example, assuming that module/function importing has gotten mixed up somewhere along the way.   Consider a case where we pass initial values `a` and `b` through a `centroid_finder()` function, which lives in `cf.py`:

```
# import cf.py as cf
import cf

a, b = ([1,2,3], [2,3,4])

cf.centroid_finder(a, b)
```

But `centroid_finder()` calls `ed()`, which lives in `ed.py`:

```
## cf.py

# import ed.py as ed
import ed

def centroid_finder(a, b):
    print(ed(a, b))

## ed.py

from numpy import sqrt, sum
import numpy as np

def ed(X2, X1):
    return sqrt(sum(np.subtract(X1,X2)**2))
```

Here, calling `centroid_finder()` will give the error you observed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e76ec6a0496c> in <module>()
      3 a, b = ([1,2,3], [2,3,4])
      4 
----> 5 cf.centroid_finder(a, b)

cf.py in centroid_finder(a, b)
      2 
      3 def centroid_finder(a, b):
----> 4         print(ed(a, b))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

That's because you imported a module, `ed.py` as `ed`...but what you wanted was to call the `ed()` function that lives inside of `ed.py`.  That's `ed.ed()`!

Changing `centroid_finder()` to call `ed.ed()` produces the desired result:

```
# cf.py 
import ed

def centroid_finder(a, b):
    print(ed.ed(a, b))
```

Now, from the main script:

```
cf.centroid_finder(a, b)
# 1.73205080757
```

There's at least one undisclosed `import` shorthand in your example code, where you call `sqrt` in `ed()`.  There isn't a natural `sqrt()` in Python, it most likely is imported from either `math` or `numpy`, e.g. `from numpy import sqrt`.  That's not a problem, per se, but given the error you're getting about modules being non-callable, you might benefit from explicitly calling functions in your code from the modules they live in.

For example, using `import numpy as np`, call `np.sqrt()` instead of just importing `sqrt()` directly.  This is a defensive programming posture that will prevent similar confusion in the future.  (You do this already with `np.subtract()` in `ed()`; it's unclear why `sqrt()` doesn't get the same treatment.)